# How I can forward a windows remote desktop connection?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, remote-desktop, iptables

I have this issue, my internet supplier only enables all ports for one local IP address, this IP is hooked to a home server that runs nginx and some web services, I need to redirect traffic for port 3389 (windows remote desktop) from another local IP so I don't know how to do it. On my home server, I'm running Ubuntu.

I already tried some iptables commands from the internet without luck.

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  646 41207 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
   19  1116 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3389 to:192.168.1.21:3389
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3389 to:192.168.1.21:3389
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:3389 to:192.168.1.21:3389
```

any advice, I don't have any experience with Iptables or redirecting traffic

Comment: How about a reverse ssh tunnel: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46271

Comment: but that is only for ssh ? or it would work with another thing? sorry for my ignorance

Comment: via SSH you can route any port to any other port. is is agnostic of the traffic running through